# Mongodb nested query with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I don't get results from nested query, loc is always null. The query parameter has proper value when I print it, and the database collection 'users' has documents with ids from the array friendsP.

```
var acquireFriendsPositions = function(db, id, res, callback) {
  var cursor = db.collection('users').find({"_id" : new ObjectId(id)}, {_id:0, friends:1});
  cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      if (doc != null) {
         friendsP = doc.friends;
         console.log(friendsP);   //I get the array friendsP
         for(var i =0; i<friendsP.length; i++)
         {
          console.log(friendsP[i]);   //friendsP[i] has proper value
           var curs = db.collection('users').find({"_id" : new ObjectId(friendsP[i])});   //but query returns null
           curs.each(function(err, loc) {
            //assert.equal(err, null);
            if(loc!= null) {
                console.log(loc);
                friendsPos.push(loc);
              }
              else {
                console.log("else");
              }
           });
         }
        promise(friendsPos, res); //here i wait for friendsPos and use it in res.send(), but friendsPos is empty because loc is always null
      } else {
         callback();  //callback does db.close();
      }
   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact code that you are using I suspect that the `friendsP` value gets hoisted and overwritten in the next `each` cycle. Meaning that you should be able to fix this by simply changing the code to `var friendsP = doc.friends` so the friendsP variable is in the function scope. If this is what is happening this is a nasty bug and you should always the declare the variables with a local scope to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Thanks Vasil, but it's the same with the local variable friendsP. Also, the cursor contains only one document because I query by id. Looks like I need dbref?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for casting Object Id:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

mongodb.ObjectID.createFromHexString(friendsP[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, guys. Actually, the problem was callback() which was closing the connection before queries were executed. Here is my new code:

```
var acquireFriendsPositions = function(db, id, res, callback) {
  db.collection('users').findOne({"_id" : new ObjectId(id)},
  function(err, item) {
    var friendsP = item.friends;
    var locFriends = [];
    promise(locFriends, res);
    var x = 0;
    for(i =0; i<friendsP.length; i++)
    {
      db.collection('users').findOne({"_id" : friendsP[i]}, function(err,subItem){
        x=x+1;
        //console.log(subItem);
        locFriends.push(subItem);
        if(x==friendsP.length)
          callback();
        });
    }
  });
};
```